# Extended Choice Parameter: can it be reactive?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters

im trying to render dinamically some parameters in jenkins. I have achieved it with extended parameter plugin using extended choice parameter.

My problem now is that the control had to be reactive to another parameter.(something similar as Active Choice Reactive Parameter, where you specify what other parameter force it refresh and you can use the other parameter value in your groovy script).

Does anybody know how can you make extended choice parameter to be reactive and change behabiour depending on other parameters value?

Comment: Anybody can give a light over this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?